# Laravel - Logged in at another location

Tags: php, mysql, session, laravel, authentication

In my web application I would like to show the user if he/she is already logged in on another machine. Also I would like to provide the user with the option to sign out of all machines except the current one.

Now I'm talking about session logins, not active sessions so updating a last_activity column isn't going to do the trick.

Now I assume the (only) way to achieve this is to decrypt the session payloads from the database and checking the Auth id from there. This is quite a heavy operation to do for every page request for 1000 logged in users.

Am I correct in this guess? Is this the correct (or only?) way to do it? Is there a better way to do this? If decrypting the Session payload is indeed the best option, how do I do this? I tried using Crypt::decrypt($session->payload) but I get 'Invalid Data' from the Crypt class.